# docker-compose pull fails but docker pull works with docker-credential-gcr

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry, google-container-optimized-os

I'm working on google container optimised OS (COS) trying to pull an image from Google Container Registry using docker-compose. I completed the the authentication using docker-credential-gcr.

Now

`docker pull gcr.io/projectname/nextjs` works

however

```
> docker-compose pull
Pulling nextjs      ... error
ERROR: for nextjs  unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials.
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the docker-compose alias did not support the gcr authentication.

The following steps fixed it.

1. Delete ~/.docker/config.json
2. change the alias in .bashrc to:

   alias docker-compose='docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v "$PWD:$PWD" -w="$PWD" cryptopants/docker-compose-gcr'
3. docker pull cryptopants/docker-compose-gcr
4. docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
5. docker-compose pull works

Comment: why was this modded down?  Is it wrong?